# ffmpeg not generating exact duration clip

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to generate exact duration clip from different HD videos using **ffmpeg3**. The clip format and video format will be same. To do so, I am using, below command

```
ffmpeg -ss 0:14:42.000 -t 0:00:02.000 -i source.mp4 -codec copy -y output.mp4
```

But command is not generating exact duration clip. The clip duration is always more than the given duration. I can use encoding and decoding step for ffmpeg, but it's very time consuming process. Any suggestions, how the problem could be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looked into [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) and found that by changing position of -ss decodes and then creates the clip, which is way more faster than command posted in question

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -ss 0:14:42.000 -codec copy -t 0:00:02.000 -y output.mp4
```